# Code crashes during execution (Assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Code compiles just fine [`NASM`]

**But as soon as I input my first value it crashes**

I don't know whats wrong, the goal is to input a string and output the reverse of the string, all while in a loop to repeat if the user says yes ('Y' or 'y')

```
**.DATA
; Initialized Data Definitions 

strlength      EQU     40
PromptStr      dd      "Please input a string (must be less than 40 characters long): ", 0
OutputStr      dd      "The reverse string is: ", 0
AgainStr       dd      "Would you like ot try again? ('Y' or 'y' for yes): ", 0 

.UDATA
; Uninitialized Data Definitions 

string         resb    strlength

.CODE
; Program Code

.STARTUP

nwln                    ; start output at a new line
PutStr      PromptStr
nwln
while:
    GetStr              string
    mov                 EBX, string

    loop_in:
        push            dword[EBX]
        add             EBX, 4
        cmp             dword[EBX], 0
        jnz             loop_in

    loop_out:
        XOR             EBX, EBX
        pop             EBX
        PutCh           [EBX]
        cmp             dword[EBX], 0
        jnz             loop_out

    nwln
    PutStr              AgainStr
    GetStr              EBX
    mov                 AL, [EBX]
    cmp                 AL, 'Y'
    jz                  while
    cmp                 AL, 'y'
    jz                  while

    Pause


.EXIT**
```

I changed the first loop to

```
loop_in:
        mov             AL, [EBX]
        push            byte[AL]
        add             EBX, 4
        cmp             byte[AL], 0
        jnz             loop_in
```

and im getting this error "error: invalid effective address"

When I change to "byte"

```
loop_in:
        push            byte[EBX]
        add             EBX, 4
        cmp             byte[EBX], 0
        jnz             loop_in
```

I get "error: invalid combination of opcode and operands"

for the line {add         EBX, 4}

So I changed

```
loop_in:
        push            EBX
        inc             EBX
        cmp             byte[EBX], 0
        jnz             loop_in

    loop_out:
        XOR             EBX, EBX
        pop             EBX
        PutCh           [EBX]
        cmp             byte[EBX], 0
        jnz             loop_out
```

and now it compiles, and I get this far

```
Please input a string (must be less than 40 characters long):
asdf
fdsaêë
```

before it crashes to windows

Comment: Use a debugger, by stepping into machine instruction. `PutStr` is not an assembler instruction.

Comment: Then show the macro file or at least link to it.

Comment: Why are you using `dword` operations for the characters? ASCII characters are typically stored as bytes.

Comment: would that cause an error?

Comment: i tried changing it and I get "error: invalid combination of opcode and operands"

Comment: Well, for example, your loop ending condition currently is that you find a `dword` with the value 0 (i.e. 4 consecutive bytes that are all 0).

Comment: im not sure how to edit it then, it wont compile if I try that

Comment: sorry im still getting used to the site

Comment: only way that it compiles is if I use `push word [EBX] ` 
or `push dword [EBX]`

Comment: Your `loop_out` is looking for a NUL terminator _before_ the string, but of course there is none, since NUL terminators are placed _after_ strings. Either put one on the stack before `loop_in`, or use a counter (a variable or a register) to determine how many times to iterate in `loop_out`.

Comment: awesome thanks I pushed a null to the stack before hand, now I don't get weird characters but it still crashes?

Comment: u cant push bytes, so you must use `word` or `dword`

Comment: Thanks guys I figured out what it was, for whatever reason it didn't like that I wasnt dec EBX during each out loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work:

```
loop_in:
    mov             AX, [EBX]
    push            AX         ; move two characters to the stack
    inc             EBX
    inc             EBX
    cmp             AX, 0
    jnz             loop_in
    cmp             AL, 0
    jnz             loop_in    ; two end-of-string checks,
                               ; because we push two characters


loop_out:
    pop             AX
    PutCh           AH
    PutCh           AL
    dec             EBX
    dec             EBX
    cmp             EBX, string
    ja              loop_out
```

Comment: It crashes right after the final reverse character is printed to the screen so im assuming something is going wrong with the loop exit

Comment: @chaosmatter: Don't you mean `cmp AH,0 / jz loop_out` instead of `cmp AX,0 / jnz loop_in`? (if the idea was to check if either of the characters is NUL)

Comment: figured it out, posted in main comments

Answer (score 0):

How did you "Compile" this, since we don't compile Assembly source, we Assemble and optionally link.

I do not have your macro file, so here I used a few functions from the C Library, but it should all be the same:

```
    push    dword [stdin]
    push    MAX_INPUT
    push    string
    call    fgets                           
    add     esp, 4 * 3

    ;~ fgets adds the NL char to string, replace with NULL
    push    string
    call    RemoveNL

    mov     esi, string
    xor     ebx, ebx
PushChar:
    movzx   eax, byte[esi + ebx]
    test    eax, eax
    jz      PopChar
    push    eax
    inc     ebx
    jmp     PushChar

PopChar:
    push    fmtchar
    push    dword [stdout]
    call    fprintf                         
    add     esp, 4 * 3    
    dec     ebx
    jnz     PopChar

    jmp     Done

RemoveNL:
    mov     esi, [esp + 4]
    xor     ecx, ecx
    dec     ecx
.FindNL:
    inc     ecx
    cmp     byte [esi + ecx], 10
    jne     .FindNL
    mov     byte [esi + ecx], 0
    ret     4
```

Now for the explanation:

```
    mov     esi, string
    xor     ebx, ebx
PushChar:
    movzx   eax, byte[esi + ebx]
    test    eax, eax
    jz      PopChar
    push    eax
    inc     ebx
    jmp     PushChar
```

Once you call whatever you call to get the input, string contains the chars.  We move the address of `string` into `esi`, zero out `ebx` to use as an index into the character array.
First we move a byte from the pointer in esi + ebx and move it into `eax` zero extending `eax` while we are at it, it moves the ASCII value of the char into the low bytes of eax, and zeros out the upper unused bytes.  We then look for the `NULL` terminator with `test` and if it is a zero at the current index, we are done with pushing values onto the stack.  If value is not 0, we push `eax` onto the stack and increment `ebx` (our index) by one and continue the loop.

```
PopChar:
    push    fmtchar
    push    dword [stdout]
    call    fprintf                         
    add     esp, 4 * 3    
    dec     ebx
    jnz     PopChar
```

There is no need to `pop` a value then `push` it again as a parameter for our print function/macro since it is already on the stack and the stack is LIFO, the last character pushed is ready to print.  Here, you only see 2 parameters pushed for `fprintf` but yet I adjust esp as if I pushed 3 parameters.  Well we remove the printed character from the stack and the next char is ready.  How do we know when to stop?  We use the number in `ebx` from our `PushChar` loop and decrease that value until it is 0.

The output:
[image]